# Cross Compiling "Wireless Tools for Linux" for Android

Tags: android, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, wireless

I've been trying to cross compile wireless tools for linux.

I've got the cross compiler for android. So I've changed the Makefile and replaced the follwoing:

```
CC =arm-eabi-gcc
AR = arm-eabi-ar
RANLIB = arm-eabi-ranlib
```

I've exported the path to these files:
    export PATH=/home/flitjes/android/system/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/:$PATH

The problem is, it compiles perfectly with standard gcc,ar and ranlib but when I replace them with the cross compile version It's erroring on every line it comes across. I'm thinking it has to do something wih the cross compiler so I'm not totally sure this is the right way of doing it.

I've tried to run the make file which resulted in this:
http://pastebin.com/jNw4j5WX

Comment: Hi Flitjes, are you able to cross-compile wireless tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering an old post since someone might get this page from a search engine:

I've cross compiled linux-wireless for the PowerPC platform for several projects.

Modifying the Makefile is the wrong way to do it.
linux-wireless (latest is 3.5 at the time of this writing) can be cross compiled by just using extra parameters. [This website shows the gist of the process](http://wiki.chumby.com/index.php/Compat-wireless_driver_on_chumby).

You want the CROSS_COMPILE macro defined for your platform.
You want linux-wireless to see where your platforms (in this case ARM) kernel sources and .config is. You do that with the KLIB and KLIB_BUILD macros. If you don't define this linux-wireless will use the information from the *current* running kernel. You really don't want that.